# Blocking Countries from accessing your website

Tags: php, api, curl

Can someone explain to me how to add more countries for "allow" at this code because I'm stuck to one country

```
//Detection IP
function getUserIpAddr(){
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
//ip from share internet
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
//ip pass from proxy
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ip;
}
//echo 'User Real IP - '.getUserIpAddr();
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => '/api/lookup?ip_address='.getUserIpAddr(),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: KCrSdLEh1IwoQMfEUVlAH5a'//API
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$user_log = json_decode($response,true);
//var_dump($user_log);
$user_ip = $user_log['ip'];
$user_country = $user_log['country'];
$user_status = $user_log['privacy']["proxy"];

if($user_country !=='US'):
die('<h2 style="text-align:center; margin:2% auto;">You are unauthorized to access this page.</h2><hr>
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;"> <p> Its look like you are from outside of Germany/Austria and trying access our system.If not, Please clean browser and try again.<Thanks.></p></div>

');
endif;

if($user_status == 0):
die('<h2 style="text-align:center; margin:2% auto;">You are unauthorized to access this page.</h2><hr>
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;"> <p><b>Your IP : </b> '.$user_ip.'<br> Its look like you are using proxy/vpn to access our system.Please disabled the proxy/vpn, clean browser and try again.<Thanks.></p></div>

');
endif;
```

the code work fine, but i  want to add multiple countries and when i try it ends up with error

```
if($user_country !=='US'):
```

something like

```
if($user_country !=='US,CA,IT'):
```

thanks for help!!!

Comment: There's a lot of detail here about the background, but your actual problem is quite fundamental - you can't use the `!==` operator to compare against a list.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$allowed_country = ['US', 'CA', 'IT'];

if (in_array($user_country, $allowed_country)) {
    //... do other
}
```

If you need "negative"...

```php
if (!in_array($user_country, $allowed_country)) {
    // do ur stuff
}
```

Remember the mark ! means "not"

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me!!!